# Finding all n-tuples with elements in {1,2,3} such that it begins and ends with a 1

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be the set of all n-tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ such that $a_i$ lies in $\{1,2,3\}$. Count how many such tuples begin with $1$ and end with $1$ and contain ${\bf exactly}$ k $1's$ and $k+2 \leq n$.

Notice since we are placing 1 at the begining and at the end then we want $k-2$ $1's$ in between so as to have exactly k 1's. We have the situation

$$ (1, a_2, a_3,..., a_{n-1}, 1) $$

So, to place k 1's in n-2 boxes we can do this in ${n-2 \choose k-1}$ ways but then in the remaining boxes which is $n-2-(k-1) = n-k-1$ there can be $2$ or $3$ so we have in total

$$ {n-2 \choose k-1} 2^{n-k-1} $$

Is this correct reasoning?

Added: if we want to generalize, say the $a_i's$ can now lie in $\{1,2,...,M\}$, in this case, to answer the question, we would have

$$ {n-2 \choose k-1} (M-1)^{n-k-1} $$

Comment: Does the parameter $k$ indicate the total number of $1$s, or the total number minus two (the one at the front and back)? In the former case, we have to choose $k - 2$ locations for the remaining $1$s, out of $n-2$ possible locations. In the latter case, we have to choose $k$ locations out of $n-2$ possible locations. How did you arrive at $k - 1$ for the remaining $1$s?